# Using Firebase Analytics with SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-analytics

I recently installed Firebase Analytics in my SwiftUI app.  Everything works great except the automatic screen views.  Am I obligated to call AnalyticsEventScreenView for every view I would like to track?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes - due to the way SwiftUI views are structured, Analytics only sees `NotifyingMulticolumnSplitViewController`.

You'll have to send screen views manually (as [stated in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews)), like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        NavigationLink(destination: OneView()) {
          Text("One")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: TwoView()) {
          Text("Two")
        }
      }
      .navigationTitle("Choose a screen")
      .onAppear() {
        Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView,
                           parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "\(ContentView.self)",
                                        AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: "\(ContentView.self)"])
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct OneView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("1")
      .onAppear() {
        Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView,
                           parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "\(OneView.self)",
                                        AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: "\(OneView.self)"])
      }
  }
}

struct OneView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    OneView()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding!  I did read in the docs regarding Analytics looking for the underlining UIViewController, but wanted to ask to be sure I wasn't missing anything.  Manually calling the AnalyticsEventScreenView works great.

Answer (score 13):

Firebase `9.0.0` [has introduced new APIs](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseAnalyticsSwift/CHANGELOG.md) that are specific to `SwiftUI` and have exited beta. There is now a `View` extension that implements a `ViewModifier` that provides you some functionality:

```
func analyticsScreen(name: String, 
                     class: String = "View", 
                     extraParameters: [String: Any] = [:])
```

[Analytics+SwiftUI.swift](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseAnalyticsSwift/Sources/Analytics%2BSwiftUI.swift)

For example:

```
struct MyView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hey")
       .analyticsScreen(
           name: "Screen Name", 
           extraParameters: [
              AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "\(type(of: self))",
              AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: "\(type(of: self))"
           ]
       )  
   }
}
```

Comment: @Dom For sure!! I was looking for answers on what was the difference between `FirebaseAnalytics` or `FirebaseAnalyticsSwift`, and after doing some research and finding my own answers, and then coming across this post, I realized my responsibility to share :)

Comment: If I have `FirebaseAnalyticsSwift` do i still need `FirebaseAnalytics`?

Comment: @lr058 I believe so. You can their Readme here - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/SwiftPackageManager.md (if you're using SPM) ore if you're using Cocoapods here - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Same Peter's answer but automatically generating the ids

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct OneView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("1")
      .onAppear() {
        Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView,
                           parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "\(type(of: self))",
                                        AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: "\(type(of: self))"])
      }
  }
}

struct OneView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    OneView()
  }
}
```